# PUT type request with a file in AJAX arrives without data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a request in a Laravel form (Blade).
To create the object I use a POST type request but to modify it I use a PUT type request.
I have to use AJAX and I have to send a file in the same request.
I have searched for information and with the POST type, it works correctly, but with the PUT type the request is empty.
I have been researching and testing and I have realized that the problem comes from this line of code within my "processData: false," request.
The problem is that if I don't put this line I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation".
That it was the same error that appeared in the POST request, so searching the internet I solved it like this.
Could someone help me to make the PUT request with the attached file?

My code:

```
const type_request = 'PUT';
const url_request = '{{ route('put_update_login', ['client' => $client, 'id' => $login->id]) }}';
let data_form = new FormData(document.getElementById(id_form));
                $.ajax({
                    type: type_request,
                    url: url_request,
                    data: data_form,
                    dataType: "json",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.hasOwnProperty("route")) {
                            window.open(response['route'], "_self").focus();
                        } else {
                            $('#alert_error').removeAttr('hidden');
                            $("#alert_error").fadeTo(20000, 500000);
                            let errors = response['errors'];
                            $.each(errors, function (index, value) {
                                $("#alert_error").last().html(value);
                            });
                            $(':button').prop('disabled', false);
                            $('#spinner_form').prop('hidden', true);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The differences between the POST and PUT version is the "type_request" and the "url_request".

Thanks in advance

Comment: "with the PUT type the request is empty" — How are you determining that it is empty?

Comment: I know it's empty because in PHP I perform a $request->all() and an empty array appears in the debug.